# A misconception about the disjoint union and the tangent bundle

Tags: elementary-set-theory, manifolds

I thought that the disjoint union of two sets $X$ and $Y$ was the set of points that were in $X$ or in $Y$ but not in both.
I now know that I was wrong: it is a set with a copy of each set, roughly speaking:
$$
              X\sqcup Y= \{0\}\times X \cup \{1\}\times Y
$$
But now, a question arises: if we consider the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{R}^2$, we have
$$
           T(\mathbb{R}^2)=\underset{x\in\mathbb{R}^2}{\coprod}T_x\mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{R}^4
$$
Is this correct?

Comment: The same reasoning shows that the tangent bundle of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is (isomorphic to) $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$.

Comment: You have the definition of disjoint union incorrect at the start. It is a set that contains two disjoint subsets isomorphic to both A and B, and nothing else. Even if A and B are not disjoint themselves, the disjoint union contains "copies" of them, so the elements common to A and B have two counterparts. With all that said, though, the symbolic definition you have is correct.

Comment: @Tac-Tics I said "know I know that I was wrong"... Maybe I was unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tangent bundle of $R^2$ is trivial, so it is isomorphic to $R^4$. But the tagent bundle of the sphere $S^2$ is not trivial, since the euler class of $S^2$ is $2$. It is not the product $S^2\times R^2$, you can express it also as the union $x\in S^2,$  $T_xS^2$.